# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

My code compares two arrays and shows items that are in both arrays. I can get this to successfully print to the console to transform a paragraph is proving more challenging.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at compareArrays (pen.js:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html?key=iFrameKey-ae252606-6389-a594-b844-2cecca064c7d:20)
compareArrays @ pen.js:25
onclick @ index.html?key=iFrameKey-ae252606-6389-a594-b844-2cecca064c7d:20

I understand I have to use the innerHTML method but unsure what my errors mean

```
<button id="search" onclick="compareArrays()" required>Search</button>
<p id="results"></p>
```

```
function compareArrays () {
  // Interate the first array
  for (var i = 0; i < restaurantsOne.length; i++) {
    // Iterate the second array 
    for (var j = 0; j < restaurantsTwo.length; j++){
      // Compare the two arrays
      if (restaurantsOne[i] == restaurantsTwo[j]){
        // console.log(restaurantsOne[i]);
        // Show results in paragraph
        document.getElementById("#results").innerHTML = restaurantsOne[i] 

      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Ultimate I would like each item, restaurantsOne[i], that is in both arrays to print to a new paragraph.

Comment: There's no element with id of `#results` in the document at the time you're trying to refer it.

Comment: You may try to e.g. put the script right before enclosing body tag, or wrap it into a `load` event callback.

Comment: @HynekS Won't a click listener be OK in this case?

Comment: @Teemu Good question. Yes, it is, there is an issue with redundant `#`, not with DOM not being loaded yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's because of your document.getElementById.

It should be like this

```
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = restaurantsOne[i]
```

(no #)

The # can be used with the [document.querySelector method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: This is closer to the solution. In this particular code snippet there are two items in both arrays. By removing # it only printed the last item that's in both arrays.

It should make a new paragraph everytime an item in both arrays is encountered. The console.log(restaurantsOne[i]) prints Nandos and KFC. When I turn it into a comment and use innerHTML it only displays KFC. Is that because there is only one paragraph

Comment: Then I think you need to use append instead of innerHTML.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Answer (score 1):

The DOM doesn't exist at the time your script is running, so no element is found.

Either move your script to the bottom of your HTML page:

```
  <script>...</script>
</body>
```

Or wrap it all in an `onload` listener:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // All your code
};
```

Also note that your ID most likely doesn't contain a `#` - you probably don't have or want this:

```
<p id="#results"></p>
```

Either remove it:

```
document.getElementById("results")
```

Or use `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector("#results")
```

Comment: Not a good practice to start an id with `#`, though, it would mess the references in stylesheets.

Comment: Yes, I agree - and how would you use `querySelector`? `##results`??